# Prime conjecture

Tags: c++, primes

I am trying to solve [this SPOJ question](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIMEZUK/).

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<cstdio>
#include<math.h>
#define l long long
 using namespace std;
l chk(l a)
{
    for(int i=2;i<=sqrt(a);++i)
    {
        if(a%i==0)
        {
            return a/i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
main()
{
//  freopen("in.txt","r",stdin);
    int t,n,a;
    l prod=1,flag;
    //t=inp();
    cin>>t;
    for(int j=1;j<=t;++j)
    {
        cin>>n;
        //n=inp();
        if(n==0)
        prod=-1;
        else
        prod=1;
        while(n--)
        {
            cin>>a;
            //a=inp();
            prod*=a;
        }
        ++prod;
        flag=chk(prod);
        if(!flag)
        printf("Case #%d: %lld\n",j,prod);
        else
        printf("Case #%d: %lld\n",j,flag);
    }
}
```

I am getting the right answer for the sample test case, but when I submit, I am getting the wrong answer.  Any hints?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately, this question appears to be off-topic because it is about solving a problem rather than asking for a Code Review. We improve code cleaniness on this site, we don't help in fixing incorrect results of code.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot help you with your issue before commenting and fixing on the formating of your code :

1. Remove whatever you want to remove before going through code reviews.
2. Give your function relevant names and add some documentation and unit tests.
3. Indent your code properly
4. Define your local variables in the smallest possible scope and as late as possible to make things easier to track.
5. Don't use macros to define types. C/C++ provides you different ways to do this (`typedef`) and this is not even required here as it just obfuscates the code.
6. Use `for` loops over `while` whenever you can to make things clearer.
7. Don't compute `sqrt` many times as it is an expensive operation.
8. Use [the correct return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main) for `main`.
9. Using `using namespace std;` is [usually frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Here's what I have for the time being. We cannot really help you

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

long long chk(long long a)
{
    long long root = sqrt(a);
    for(int i=2; i <= root; i++)
    {
        if(a%i==0)
        {
            return a/i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    for(int i=1; i<=t; i++)
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        long long prod = (n==0) ? -1 : 1;
        while(n--)
        {
            int a;
            cin>>a;
            prod*=a;
        }
        ++prod;
        long long flag = chk(prod);
        printf("Case #%d: %lld\n",i,flag ? flag : prod);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if you want to have actual helpful answers, you should give more information about what you are trying to do and how.

Comment: thanx for your help but i found mistake in my code while commenting :D

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with function `chk`, which is supposed to return the largest prime factor of a given integer. Unfortunately, it returns the largest **not-necessarily-prime** factor (smaller than the given input).

For example, `chk(75)` will return `75/3`, which is `25` - obviously **not a prime**.

Here is one way to fix this problem (recursive implementation):

```
typedef unsigned long long t_ull;

t_ull chk(t_ull a)
{
    t_ull root = (t_ull)sqrt(a);
    for(t_ull i=2; i<=root; i++)
    {
        if(a%i==0)
        {
            return chk(a/i);
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Please note that if no prime factor is found, then the function returns the input itself (which is prime).

This allows you to revoke the use of `flag`, and simply print the output of `chk`:

```
cout<<"Case #"<<j<<": "<<chk(prod)<<endl;
```